# Why are my LVM Partition Sizes Different to What I have Entered?

Tags: partition, lvm, gnome-disks

I'm trying to create a 64GB LVM partition for my root volume.

```
lvcreate -L 64G volume0 -n lv_root
```

However, when I start gnome-disks the partition is listed as 69GB? Incidentially this is the same size I get using:

```
df -H
```

How would I create a logical volume that is 64GB in size rather than 69GB? Is this something to do with GB vs GiB or is this a quirk of LVM?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in your assumption that it is GB vs GiB. lvcreate uses GiB where as gnome-disks is using GB

64 Gibibyte = 68.72 Gigabyte

Comment: 64GB  is  59.60GiB as you can't use floating point with -L I'd suggest creating it as mebibyte ie -L 61035M